# displaying a list of objects to a view having a ICollection<generic> object as one of its item

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am a new to MVC and I am working on a small class project where i have to generate a multiple choice question after getting data from the database.

My question is present in Question table which has questionId and questionText columns and I have a choices table where I save choices for the questions, this table has choiceId, questionId and choiceText columns (each question can have any number of choices, so I am saving choices in a seperate table).

My Models:

```
Question Model:

namespace OnlineExamination.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Question
    {
        public Question()
        {
            this.Choices = new HashSet<Choice>();
            this.Exams = new HashSet<Exam>();
        }

        public int questionId { get; set; }
        public string questionText { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Choice> Choices { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Exam> Exams { get; set; }
    }
}
```

my controller:

```
public ActionResult Exam()
        {
            Question ques = new Question();

            using (OnlineExamEntities db = new OnlineExamEntities())
            {

                ques.questionText = db.Questions.Where(z => z.questionId == 1000).Select(z => z.questionText).SingleOrDefault();

               var query = (from p in db.Choices
                                where p.questionId == 1000
                                select new
                                {
                                    choiceId = p.choiceId,

                                    choiceText = p.choiceText,

                                    isCorrect = p.isCorrect
                                }).ToList();

                   ques.Choices = query.Select(x => new Choice
                                {
                                    choiceId = x.choiceId,
                                    choiceText = x.choiceText,
                                    isCorrect = x.isCorrect
                                }).ToList();

                return View(ques);


            }
        }
```

I am able to get the data from the tables using the above controller.
I am having trouble in displaying the ICollection object and its properties in the view.

my View:

```
@model OnlineExamination.Models.Question


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Exam";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @Html.Label(ViewData["qText"].ToString());

    <ul>
        <li>

           @for(int i =0 ; i< Model.Choices.Count ;i++ ){

               Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Choices[i]);

            }

         </li>

    </ul>
}
```

I am able to get the question text onto the view using "        @Html.Label(Model.questionText.ToString());"

I am trying a similar code block for choices as well which is not working,

code i am using to display choices:
 @Html.Label(Model.Choices[i]) which is not working. I am not able to access the properties of the Choice class.

**Please help  me in solve this issue.**

Comment: Hi, please let us know what is going wrong. what is the error? thank you.

Comment: `Choice` is a complex object so you need a `HtmlHelper` method for each property in the object - `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Choices[i].choiceId);`, `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Choices[i].choiceText)` etc

Comment: If you want to select only one `Choice` from may, then you should be using radio buttons and your `Question` view model should contain a property `int SelectedAnswer` to bind to the `ID` property of the selected `Choice` (you appear to be using checkboxes which would not be appropriate)